# What type to use for the `CardElement` in typescript for `@stripe/react-stripe-js` package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, stripe-payments

I can't for the life of me figure out what type I should be using for this import:

```
import { CardElement } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
```

For the `stripe` and `elements` props you drill from the consumer and for the optional token object for example I used these types correctly:

```
import { Stripe, StripeElements, CreateTokenCardData } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
```

but for `CardElement` I just can't find the right type to use. I looked at the definition files inside `node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js` as well as `node_modules/@stripe/react-stripe-js` but no luck.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...but for CardElement I just can't find the right type to use.

The type you're looking for is likely the **`CardElementComponent`** type, which you can import along with the component as follows:

```
import { CardElement, CardElementComponent } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
```

You can reference the type definition, along with the type definitions of all the other components included in `@stripe/react-stripe-js` in this file here:

https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/blob/e13fae556b1a667a5dfa1130c00d5ec4c2bc154e/src/types/index.ts#L78